# Why is Bootstrap 4 locally not loading in a Django Project?

Tags: css, django

I am using Django to write my first blog project. and using bootstrap 4 in my project works fine until now but suddenly it stops working. I didn't make any changes to my project, especially to the CSS link. here is the code.

```
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css'%}">
```

even I try to use bootstrap.css but not working
the server runs correctly there is no error even in the console.

Answer (score 2):

add this code into your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and ensure that in your settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Read your if statement and debug value again.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little more detail about the problem and possible solutions:

### Cause number 1: you changed settings.DEBUG to False

The root cause here is that the `runserver` management command from `django.contrib.staticfiles` will service the files without looking for a STATIC_ROOT. It will directly serve them from the `static` subfolder in the application directories and any directories specified in `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS`. When you turn DEBUG to off, it will stop this behavior and will look for the files in `settings.STATIC_ROOT`.

[More information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

### Cause number 2: you installed a package that overrides runserver

The behavior above only applies when you use runserver from staticfiles. Some packages override the runserver command and do not extend the runserver command from static files, which then causes the special behavior to fail. It will then behave as if `settings.DEBUG` is set to False.

For both cases, the solution is:

- Define the STATIC_ROOT variable in settings and point it to a directory on your file system and
- Create that directory if it doesn't exist, after which
- You run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` and
- You create the URLs as described by @AndreyMaslov in your root urlconf, but instead let them apply for when DEBUG is False

Of course, for case one, you can also set DEBUG back to True.

Answer (score 0):

if you sure added correctly static files or assets and links.
but your CSS files are not coming up, you could run your server on **insecure** mode.

setting.py:

```
DEBUG = False
```

try this :

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```